# How do I render this form using fields_for in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have problem adding a nested model to a form. Specifically, nothing appears in this form section.

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
...
    <% fields_for :bigip do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :bgname %>
        <%= f.text_field :bguser %>
        <%= f.text_field :bgpassword %>
    <% end %>
...
```

Here are the underlying models and controllers.

**pool.rb**

```
class Pool < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :bigip, inverse_of: :pool
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bigip, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**bigip.rb**

```
class Bigip < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :pool
end
```

**pools_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @pool = Pool.new
    @pool.build_bigip
end
```

Comment: `<%= f.fields_for :big_ip do |big_ip_form| %>...`  Note the "=" and "f.".

Answer (score 1):

devil is in details :)

I simply missed "=" in line "<% fields_for :bigip do |f| %>"